# Mostrar datos sin repetir

Tags: sql, sql-server

necesito ayuda con mi consulta de sql.
Mi consulta es:

```
select * from matricula
```

y me muestra estos datos:

```
nummatri   fechamatri    dnialum    idnivel   idgrado  idsecc   año
3          2017-12-20    12357890    2          7       14      2018
```

Quiero que me muestre la descripción de cada id, es decir, en vez de

```
2=secundaria
7=primero
14=A
```

Utilizo esta consulta:

```
SELECT    Distinct  m.nummatr,m.fechamat, m.idalumno,
n.descnivel,g.descgrado, s.descsecc
FROM            
matricula as m INNER JOIN
nivel AS N ON m.idnivel = n.idnivel INNER JOIN
grado as g ON n.idnivel = g.idnivel INNER JOIN
seccion as s ON n.idnivel = s.idnivel AND g.idgrado = s.idgrado
```

pero me muestra estos datos:

```
3   2017-12-20  12357890    Secundaria  Cuarto  A

3   2017-12-20  12357890    Secundaria  Cuarto  B

3   2017-12-20  12357890    Secundaria  Primero A

3   2017-12-20  12357890    Secundaria  Primero B

3   2017-12-20  12357890    Secundaria  Quinto  A

3   2017-12-20  12357890    Secundaria  Quinto  B

3   2017-12-20  12357890    Secundaria  Segundo A

3   2017-12-20  12357890    Secundaria  Segundo B

3   2017-12-20  12357890    Secundaria  Tercero A

3   2017-12-20  12357890    Secundaria  Tercero B
```

¿Cuál sería la consulta correcta para que me muestre lo que deseo?

Comment: Hola Adrian. Falta que nos describas la estructura y contenido de las otras tablas (nivel, grado, seccion) para poder entender bien tu pregunta.

Comment: ¿Probaste con `left join`? Cuéntanos cómo te va con ese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está con los joins que le haces a las tablas `grado` y `nivel`.

En tu consulta, estás haciendole joins a esas 2 tablas a partir de la tabla `nivel`. Esto no parece correcto. En realidad, las 3 tablas deberían relacionarse directamente a la tabla principal `matricula`.

Puede que me equivoque un poco con los nombres de columnas, porque no describistes todas las tablas, pero la consulta debería ser la siguiente:

```
SELECT m.nummatr,
       m.fechamat,
       m.idalumno,
       n.descnivel,
       g.descgrado,
       s.descsecc
  FROM matricula AS m
 INNER JOIN nivel AS n ON m.idnivel = n.idnivel
 INNER JOIN grado AS g ON m.idgrado = g.idgrado
 INNER JOIN seccion AS s ON m.idsecc = s.idsecc
```

Nota que si la consulta está diseñada correctamente, entonces no hay necesidad de incluir un `DISTINCT`, que es el keyword que instintivamente agregamos a la consulta cuando nos devuelve duplicados que no entendemos.

Answer (score 0):

Deberias hacer algo asi:

SELECT m.nummatr, m.fechamat, m.idalumno, n.campoNombreTablaNivel, g.campoNombreTablaGrado, s.campoNombreTablaSeccion
  FROM matricula m, nivel n, grado g, seccion s 
 WHERE m.idnivel = n.idnivel 
   AND m.idgrado = g.idgrado
   AND m.idseccion = s.idseccion

IMPORTANTE:

Las tablas nivel debe tener primary ker idnivel, los mismo para las tablas grado y seccion

ejemplo:  alter table nivel add constraint PK_NIVEL primary key (idnivel)

y la tabla matricula debe hacer referencia a las tablas nivel, grado y seccion, es decir un foreign key

ejemplo:  alter table matricula add constraint CONS_001 foreign key (idnivel) references nivel (idnivel)

y que los campos idnivel, idgrado y idseccion no permita nulos,

todo esto para garantizar una buena integridad de datos